# Is it possible to display y-axis with waveform in wavesurfer.js?

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

I am wondering if it is possible to display y-axis on a waveform in wavesurfer.js and to lock the y-axis scale.

I have set an integer 1 as the barHeight. But not sure what the 1 exactly means.

What I am looking for is to display y-axis on a waveform or to lock the y-axis.